# Is there a way to associate MathMl 3.0 Version in XSD while using MathMl 2.0 at the same time?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm a software engineer and I'm currently working on a project that will validate the validity of an xml file with MathML tagging against an xsd I have. The MathML 2.0 version is included in that xsd I currently have, but some of the xml my company receive contains the MathML 3.0-only tagging.

Let's imagine I have two xml files with mathml tags; one of them has tags and elements that are only visible in MathML 2.0, while the other has tags and elements that are only visible in MathML 3.0. I also have an xsd that includes or calls MathML 2.0.

Whether they have MathML 2.0 or MathML 3.0 tagging, I want these two XML files to be checked against the XSD I have.

Is there a way or an option in xsd I can use to call MathML2.0 or use Mathml3.0 if the xml tagging cannot be found in 2.0 version?

Need help please.

Thanks in advance.

I tried searching online to see some possible solution or other people with the same problem that will at least give me some idea to resolve my problem but i cant find one.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two parts to this problem.

First you need to find a way of building two schemas, one of which contains the MathML 2.0 schema, the other containing the MathML 3.0 schema. There are various ways you can do this, for example by using catalog mechanisms to resolve the relevant `xs:import` declarations to different source files.

Secondly you need a mechanism that decides which of these two schemas to use for validation at run-time. I would do this with a little pipeline (perhaps written in XProc) that first examines the instance using XPath to decide which dialect it is using, and then invokes the appropriate validator in the next step of the pipeline.